# Заменить Console.ReadLine или Console.ReadKey в коде на js функцию input.value в рантайме

Tags: c#, blazor, roslyn, blazor-client-side

Имеется проект на Blazor WASM, похож на try.dot.net (пишется код, затем можно его запустить)

Имеется проблема. Когда выполнение доходит до `Console.ReadLine` или `Console.ReadKey`, то приложение падает, т.к. эти инструкции возвращают `null` сразу, без возможности ввода значения

Код запускается при помощи `CSharpCompilation`

Предполагаю, что можно в рантайме заменить `Console.ReadLine` или `Console.ReadKey` на вызов `input.value` через `JSRuntime`. Но не могу понять как заменить одну конструкцию на другую

Я могу получить нужные методы через `SyntaxTree`, но как их заменить, не могу догнать. Для удобства, синтаксическое дерево можно посмотреть [тут](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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)

Comment: Зачем вам `Console` в WASM?

Comment: Создайте свой Stream, который будет представлась ввод из консоли и просто шлите в этот поток своим данные. Переписывать код не нужно, просто перед запуском указанного кода, нужно перенаправить ввод консоли на свой поток.

Comment: На условном https://sharplab.io или https://try.dot.net решил потестировать небольшой кусок кода. И вот нужно ввести значение, я по привычке буду писать Console.ReadLine. Здесь WASM для того, чтобы отобразить окно ввода кода, а затем закинуть этот код в CSharpCompilation и запустить его и отобразить результат

Comment: @aepot спасибо большое за наводку, попробую такой вариант

Comment: Отоюразить окно ввода можно с помощью одной строки js - `prompt`.